# Set language springMVC/Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm working on a webapp using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf with Java-configuration. In the template for the `html` page the language is set to be Swedish through this code:

```
<html lang="sv">
```

And the encoding is set to UTF-8 through this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

But for some reason, that will not display the swedish letters.

I tried changing the `<html>` tag to the XHTML version `xml:lang="en"` but it makes no difference.

Since I'm still very new to Spring and Thymeleaf, I don't know where something might be wrong, or where the language/charset is supposed to be stated/set so I'm giving you the thymeleaf configuration code and the page controller:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
                resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("index");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to `templateResolver` in `ThymeleafConfig`:

```
resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

As remarked in the [docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.4.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/spring4/view/ThymeleafViewResolver.html#setCharacterEncoding-java.lang.String-) `setCharacterEncoding`:

> Specifies the character encoding to be set into the response when the
>   view is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

I got proper encoding only when property `characterEncoding` was added to both `ServletContextTemplateResolver` and `ThymeleafViewResolver`.

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    ...
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    ...
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```